# Playing audio in background of Windows 8 app with Player Framework

Tags: vb.net, windows-8

I am using the Microsoft Player Framework, http://playerframework.codeplex.com/, to play both audio and video files in a Windows 8 app written in VB. The AudioCategory property is already set to BackgroundCapableMedia, and the audio background task has been registered. According to the forums, http://playerframework.codeplex.com/discussions/395898, this should be all that is needed. I am hoping that someone has had experience with the control and knows what is missing that is preventing the audio from actually playing while the app is not active.

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared that you want to play audio in the background?
Go to your `Package.appxmanifest`, `Declarions Tab`, Add `Background Tasks` in `Available Contracts`. Check the `Audio Checkbox` and tell it, which xaml page it should open.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else need it...
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj841209.aspx